# Pluck primaryKey from relationship between same table

Tags: php, laravel

Cursos has a `many-to-many` relationship with Cursos and i want to get only the `primaryKey` from the related Cursos.

```
$curso = Curso::with(['thumb','interna','area','cursos_relacionados' => function($query){
    $query->pluck('curso_id');
}])->find($curso_id);
```

The problem: `Column 'curso_id' in field list is ambiguous`.

I could do this:

```
DB::table('cursos_has_cursos_relacionados')->select('curso_relacionado_id')
->where('curso_id','=',$curso_id)->pluck('curso_relacionado_id')->toArray();
```

But i would like to know if **its possible and how to add** a alias to the `with()` method and use the first sample of code.

## UPDATE

This is the relation

```
public function cursos_relacionados(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Curso','cursos_has_cursos_relacionados','curso_id','curso_relacionado_id');
}
```

Comment: Eager loading when using find doesn't offer many advantages.  You shouldn't be using pluck or any function that will actually execute the query inside of the with closure.'

Comment: What is the purpose of loading `cursos_relacionados`? If you want to get the primary key it already exists in the `Curso` model's table? Please explain what you're trying to do here

Comment: @Paras , The `Curso` 050 is related with two other `Curso` (`cursos_relacionados`). But the `primaryKeys` have the same name(it's the same `table`). I want to know if is possible to set a alias to the `with()` method and return the `primaryKey`.

Comment: can you post the relationship function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, i couldn't find anything about setting a alias on the with() method. But, if anyone finds himself here, loking for the same anwser. Try the following code, it should work just fine

```
$curso = Curso::with(['thumb.media_root','interna.media_root','objetivos_media.media_root','area'])->find($curso_id);       
$curso->cursos_relacionados = DB::table('cursos_has_cursos_relacionados')->select('curso_relacionado_id')->where('curso_id','=',$curso_id)->pluck('curso_relacionado_id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem: `Column 'curso_id' in field list is ambiguous.`

You need to specify table: `'thumb.curso_id'` or the table you want.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but both tables have the same name, how do I specify then?